# How to convert a `Vec<u8>` to a different struct, and dropping Vec, whilst having ownership on other struct

Tags: rust, unsafe

I have a function that reads a `Vec<u8>` from disk that I want to interpret as the ext2 super block (which is a packed struct).

So I used:

```
unsafe {&*(raw_super.as_ptr() as *const Super block)}
```

The problem is when the function returns the `Vec` is dropped, so the super block is only 0s

I want a way to transform the Vec into a super block and own the data in super block, with if possible a small cost abstraction

Comment: I also tried core::même::transmute and transmute copy but i couldnt tell the compiler m'y Vec IS large enough

Comment: You could blit the data onto a `#[repr(C)]` struct, but otherwise this would be unsound because `Vec` owns a heap allocation, which I doubt your struct is designed to manage.

Comment: @cdhowie might be possible to `Vec::into_boxed_slice()`, then transmute that into a `Box<struct>`, but it does feel dodgy as all hell.

Comment: @Masklinn I don't think that would be sound for multiple reasons.

Comment: @cdhowie Would you mind elaborating? I think it would be sound, but dodgy.

Comment: An ext2 superblock is stored on disk in little endian format. Your struct in memory is laid out in using the target machine's native endianness. If you want the code to be somewhat portable, you can't just load the data from disk into an in-memory struct. You should use the `byteorder` crate instead.

Comment: @SvenMarnach In particular, `u8`'s alignment is 1 but I'm sure this struct does not have alignment of 1. So, in fact, the unsafe conversion in OP's code may also result in UB due to unaligned access.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks, that's true. (It's usually not a problem in practice, since memory allocations have an alignment of at least 16, but it's unsound nonetheless.)

Comment: @cdhowie IIRC `#[repr(packed)]` structs are always aligned by one as well, and OP states their struct is `packed`. That still leaves the endianness problem though.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the excellent [`bytemuck`](https://crates.io/crates/bytemuck) crate to safely cast the data in your `Vec<u8>` to `&SuperBlock`. For example:

```
use bytemuck::{Pod, Zeroable};

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Pod, Zeroable)]
#[repr(C, packed)]
pub struct SuperBlock {
    foo: u16,
    bar: u32,
}

pub struct OwnedSuperBlock {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

impl OwnedSuperBlock {
    pub fn new(data: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        OwnedSuperBlock { data }
    }

    pub fn as_super_block(&self) -> &SuperBlock {
        bytemuck::from_bytes(&self.data)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3b12a630cb41523f6757387f33199d19)

This code doesn't use `unsafe` owing to guarantees provided by `bytemuck::Pod` trait and derive macro. They ensure that it's safe to cast bytes in the vector to a `&SuperBlock`, also checking that the bytes are correctly sized and aligned. Finally, the whole thing is zero-copy and involves minimal run-time cost (just the data size check).

Note that this code assumes that the on-disk format uses the same endianness as the architecture you compile your program on.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try that... I've found: unsafe { (vec.as_ptr() as *const ExtSuperBlock).read() }
But it copied the value which isn't great

Comment: @Sxmourai If you do that, be sure to include `#[repr(C, packed)]` in your struct, so that it has an alignment of 1. If it's ok to copy the value, you can use `*bytemuck::from_bytes(&vec)`, and you don't need the "owned" struct at all.

Comment: I don't think bytemuck will perform the potentially required enidanness conversion, so I'm not sure this will work for the OP's use case.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Indeed it won't (and can't, as it doesn't modify or copy data). This answer assumes that the code is run on the architecture of the same endianness as the on-disk format - as does the OP. I've now made the assumption explicit.

Comment: @user4815162342 ext2 uses little endian for the superblock regardless of the machine architecture. Moreover, ext4 uses big endian for the journal, so if the OP also wants to support that, they'll have to deal with endianness at some point.

Comment: @SvenMarnach *ext2 uses little endian for the superblock regardless of the machine architecture* - that is undisputed, but is irrelevant if the OP doesn't plan to run their program on big-endian hardware. Such architectures have become quite rare in recent decades - I haven't had access to them since early 2000s when I used SPARC. The answer is now explicit about its assumptions, which is how far I'm willing to go answering this question. If endian conversion is needed, it should be mentioned in the question, or asked in a separate one.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted in the comments before, you have to assert a couple of preconditions first:

- The endianness is correct ([ext2 uses little endian](https://extfs.readthedocs.io/internal/superblock.html))
- The alignment of `u8` and `SuperBlock` is the same (but `u8` and a [`#[repr(packed)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-alignment-modifiers) struct always fulfill that `packed` is implicitly `packed(1)`)
- The size of the `Vec<u8>` (it's `len()`) is the same as the size of a `SuperBlock`
- The order of the fields in the struct is known and the same as specified for `ext2`

So you can convert your `Vec<u8>` to a `Box<SuperBlock>` like this:

```rust
// `C` so the order of the fields in memory is known
// `packed` so the alignment is 1 and there is no padding
#[repr(C, packed)]
pub struct SuperBlock {
    foo: u16,
    bar: u32,
}

// ext2 superblocks are always little endian, so this works only for those platforms
#[cfg(target_endian = "little")]
impl SuperBlock {
    /// ## Errors
    /// Returns the vector unchanged when it's length isn't exactly the size of a `SuperBlock`
    pub fn from_vec(v: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Box<Self>, Vec<u8>> {
        if v.len() != std::mem::size_of::<SuperBlock>() {
            return Err(v);
        }
        // SAFETY:
        // `#[repr(packed)] structs have an alignment of 1, the same as u8
        // v.len() and size_of::<SuperBlock>() are the same as asserted above
        Ok(unsafe { Box::from_raw(Box::into_raw(v.into_boxed_slice()).cast::<SuperBlock>()) })
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ce579d2e1f5ad95a83590f98579783e1)

<sub>Technically, this does not *drop* the `Vec`, instead it reuses the same allocation for the returned `Box<SuperBlock>`</sub>